# Magento226: Fatal error Call to a member function setId()

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, image-upload, ui-form

I am getting this error in magento Ui component admin form , it tried changing container instead of form in Ui form , but that did not help either.

> Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function setId() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Magentos226/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

**DataSource in Ui Form**

```
<dataSource name="item_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\Item\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">igallery_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="module/item/save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

**Media Uploader Code in Ui Form**

```
<htmlContent name="gallery" sortOrder="22">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Images</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <wrapper>
            <canShow>true</canShow>
            <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
        </wrapper>
    </settings>
    <block name="gallery" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Media\Helper\Form\Gallery">
        <block class="Vendor\Events\Block\Adminhtml\Media\Helper\Form\Gallery\Image" as="content">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="parentComponent" xsi:type="string">module_article_form.module_article_form.block_gallery.block_gallery</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>                
        </block>
    </block>
</htmlContent>
```

**DataProvider**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Item;

use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
  protected $collection;
  protected $dataPersistor;
  public $_storeManager;
  protected $loadedData;

public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $blockCollectionFactory,
    DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->collection = $blockCollectionFactory->create();
    $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
    $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
}

public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();

    foreach ($items as $page) {
        $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
    }

    $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('media-item');
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $page = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
        $page->setData($data);
        $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
        $this->dataPersistor->clear('media-item');
    }

    return $this->loadedData;
  }
}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Ranjit Shinde relevant code is added please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for typo in code make sure your block path is correct `Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Media\Helper\Form\Gallery\Image` i check this code it is working for me.

```
<htmlContent name="gallery" sortOrder="22">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Images</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <wrapper>
            <canShow>true</canShow>
            <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
        </wrapper>
    </settings>
    <block name="gallery" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Media\Helper\Form\Gallery">
        <block class="Vendor\Events\Block\Adminhtml\Media\Helper\Form\Gallery\Image" as="content">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="parentComponent" xsi:type="string">module_article_form.module_article_form.block_gallery.block_gallery</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>                
        </block>
    </block>
</htmlContent>
```